# Changing size of dynamic *char

Tags: c

Is there way how to make my string to even size?

EDIT:
I need a few string in struct that have even length. So something like:

`struct msg { char * first; char * second; char * third; };`

so it is in the end something like first string "hi\0\0" second string "hello\0" third string "byebye\0\0" and i need to change them anytime+they are dynamic allocated.

Comment: Your string isn't dynamically allocated. With `malloc`, just pass a even number.

Comment: That's not dynamic allocation.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need a few string in struct that have even length..
so soemthing like:
struct msg {
        char * first;
        char * second;
        char * third;
};
so it is in the end something like
first string "hi\0\0"
second string "hello\0"
third string "byebye\0\0"
and i need to change them anytime+they are dynamic allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `strdup_even()`.

Allocate memory as needed to copy the string, plus maybe 1 more to make "even".

```
char *strdup_even(const char *str) {
  size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;  // Size needed for the _string_
  size_t len2 = len + len % 2;   // Even allocation size
  char *copy = malloc(len2);
  if (copy) {
    memcpy(copy, str, len);
    if (len2 > len) {
      copy[len] = '\0';
    }
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Sample usage

```
struct msg m;
m.first =  strdup_even("hi");
m.second = strdup_even("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc()` and `realloc()`:

```
char *string = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
strcpy(string, "hi");
string = realloc(string, STRING_SIZE+1);
string[STRING_SIZE] = '\0';
```